# MOODLE: retrieve database query

Tags: moodle

```
$condgrade = $DB->get_recordset_sql('SELECT c.fullname, gi.itemtype, gi.itemname, 
                                     gg.userid, gg.finalgrade FROM 
                                     '.$CFG->prefix.'grade_items gi 
                                     JOIN '.$CFG->prefix.'grade_grades gg ON gi.id = 
                                     gg.itemid JOIN '.$CFG->prefix.'course c ON c.id = 
                                     gi.courseid WHERE 
                                     gi.itemtype IN ("course") AND  
                                     gg.userid = '.$USER->id.'');                                                        

foreach($condgrade as $cgg)
{
   $this->content->text .= html_writer::div($cgg->fullname.'&nbsp;:&nbsp;'.round($cgg->finalgrade).'%', array('class' => 'cours')); 
}
```

Is there any other way of retrieving data directly from the query, rather using foreach loop everytime something like in mysql : `mysql_fetch_object($users);`

Answer (score 0):

Get a single record?

```
$user = $DB->get_record('user', array('id' => 1));
```

http://docs.moodle.org/dev/Data_manipulation_API#Getting_a_single_record

EDIT : As well as the recommendations from davosmith, you also need to have a unique id in the first column. Also you can just use $DB->get_records_sql() - use $DB->get_recordset_sql() if you expect a large amount of data. If you do use get_recordset_sql() then you will also need to check the query is valid with $condgrade->valid() and close it after $condgrade->close();

```
$sql = "SELECT gg.id,
               c.fullname,
               gi.itemtype,
               gi.itemname, 
               gg.userid,
               gg.finalgrade
        FROM {grade_items} gi 
        JOIN {grade_grades} gg ON gi.id = gg.itemid
        JOIN {course} c ON c.id = gi.courseid
        WHERE gi.itemtype = :itemtype
        AND gg.userid = :userid";
$params = array('itemtype' => 'course', 'userid' => $USER->id);
$condgrade = $DB->get_records_sql($sql, $params);
```

This will return an array of record objects. The array key will be whatever is in the first column. eg:

$condgrade[1] = $recordobject;

So you can access a record object directly eg:

with $condgrade[1]->fullname

But you won't know what the id is unless you retrieve it from the database. So I'm not clear why you want to access the object directly? If you can give me an example of how you would use this directly then I can try to give an answer.

Comment: No Russell, I need to get multiple records

Comment: Can you give a code example of what you want to do?

Comment: oh sorry I meant can you give an example of what you would do if you used mysql_fetch_object($users); - also just a note, in Moodle 2 you should use this syntax in the SQL - FROM {grade_items} - The $CFG->prefix was used in Moodle 1.9

Comment: Thank You Russel, but in the above mentioned query, can we not get the array of records rather with the use of foreach.

Comment: The result is an array of records - I've modified my answer above

Comment: Hello Russel England, I need your help in a moodle sql query  :https://moodle.org/mod/forum/discuss.php?d=256781, where I couldn't get any help and tried more

Answer (score 0):

```
$records = $DB->get_records_sql('SELECT c.fullname, gi.itemtype, gi.itemname, 
                                     gg.userid, gg.finalgrade FROM 
                                     {grade_items} gi 
                                     JOIN {grade_grades} gg ON gi.id = 
                                     gg.itemid JOIN {course} c ON c.id = 
                                     gi.courseid WHERE 
                                     gi.itemtype IN ("course") AND  
                                     gg.userid = :userid', array('userid' => $USER->id));
```

This will return an array of records.

Note also, the use of {tablename} notation, rather than manually inserting the $CFG->prefix and the use of ':userid' bound parameter + parameter list passed as "array('userid' => $USER->id)", which helps to protect you from SQL injection attacks.

Comment: But my question is : Is there any other way of retrieving data directly from the query, rather using foreach loop everytime something like in mysql : mysql_fetch_object($users);

Comment: Well, as stated in my answer, $DB->get_records_sql (instead of get_recordset_sql) returns a standard PHP array, so you can use any of the standard array manipulation functions to extract elements (e.g. reset, current, next, array_pop, array_shift, etc. see: http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.array.php ). Is there a particular reason why you don't want to use a foreach loop - even with mysql_fetch_object you'd probably still end up with some sort of a loop to retrieve all the values.

Comment: Hi Davosmith, sorry to interrupt you guys. I need your help in an moodle sql query : moodle.org/mod/forum/discuss.php?d=256781, where I couldn't get any help and tried my best